# Communicating from inspectedWindow.eval to extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So we can communicate from a content script to a DevTools page, but for some reason we can't communicate from inspectedWindow.eval to the rest of the extension. What I'm trying to do is extremely simple (in theory). I want to add a `copy` function to `console` so whatever you pass to `console.copy` will get copied to the clipboard when DevTools is open.

I have tried many things to get this to work. It appears that I have to do the console.copy assignment in an `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval` so that I'm dealing with the right context for `console`. However, I don't know how to send that to my function that actually puts the content to the clipboard... Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know why this is so difficult...

I've tried `chrome.extension.sendMessage` but I can't do that in an `inspectedWindow.eval` because chrome.extension` is not defined (makes sense). I just don't know where to go with this and my brain is going to explode...

Comment: I should probably mention that while I never found a solution for this problem, I did realize that `console.copy` is actually already available as a built-in Chrome api 